# python percache on staticmethod

Tags: python, caching, static-methods

I am trying to use [percache](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/percache) package on a class `staticmethod` but it seems not to work. Are there any restriction on caching static methods?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works fine. **Example**

```
import percache

cache = percache.Cache('pop.txt')


class M():

    @staticmethod
    @cache
    def f(a, b):
        print ('cool')
        return a + b


print (M.f('pop', 'corn'))
print (M.f('pop', 'corn'))

cache.close()
```